# Which of these slider handles have the most affordance?

Tags: filter, controls, affordance, perceived-affordance

Working on a filter for **desktop**,  and need to decide which kind of filter handle giveS the user the obvious impression that they can use it as a slider.

[image]

Any other suggestions besides the above are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Combine 1+2 with a little bit of seasoning.**

Option 2 is great because the selected range is thicker and a bit darker.  But the black handles don't provide any affordance.  So I would replace them with circular handles from Option 1, but why not throw in a bit of drop shadow for that extra-affordance?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much of the context or output, I'd say four initial things:

- remember the affordance in context (is it to be manipulated by mouse or finger, or both, and which of these better indicate that/both of those interactions?)
- similarly, remember the affordance must be 'visible' in the context of use (straight up, regardless of device, 4 and 1 throw up 'visibility' flags because of colour and sizing.)
- what are people used to? (for the output, in similar interactions, in similar contexts, etc)
- What can there be as a failsafe? Text input? ([Sliders and Accessibility: Usability of sliders for users with disabilities](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42522/sliders-and-accessibility-usability-of-sliders-for-users-with-disabilities))

And then test!